# Is it possible to only detect motion on only specific regions (motion)?

Tags: camera, motion, security

I have a rudimentary motion detector but trees waving in the wind (and especially their shadows on the roof) are causing more false positives than I'm willing to accept.

I would like the motion detector to only save pictures when it detects motion on certain zones. If possible I would like to define these zones as a binary mask. Is this possible?

If not with motion, is this possible with some other linux packages?

Comment: Off topic as the question is not Pi specific.  Linux packages work the same on all Linux boxes.

Comment: Yes of course but the Pi stackexchange has the most questions about the motion package especially as used as a home security camera. And it's not suitable for the other exchanges because it's not about the code/math of the motion detection but only about the usage of it.

Comment: Try a different sensor.

Comment: You seem to be asking about `spatial filtering` - which is apparently done in living things as a precursor to motion detection [REF](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=spatial+filtering+motion+detection&atb=v278-1&ia=web). Given the amount of research on the topic, I'd be surprised if there's not some code (somewhere) that does that. Perhaps a more fruitful line of inquiry for your interest is GitHub, or perhaps a more specialized SE site or forum: Signal Processing, AI, Machine Vision. Interesting question, BTW.

Comment: This one may be useful: https://forums.ni.com/t5/Machine-Vision/bd-p/200  Or maybe [this one?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/spatial-filtering-and-its-types/)

Comment: What software are you using for motion detection now?